# Ubuntu 14.04 showing as external device, not separate OS beside Win8

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I recently did an update of Windows 8, and since then my toshiba satpro will only boot into Windows, and Ubuntu shows as an external drive in the restart menu.

I have tried using easybcd to change the boot menu but changes appear to be undone upon reboot.

Secure boot and fast boot aare both disabled.

my system uses UEFI - which I suspect is responsible.

Thank you.

Comment: EasyBCD isn't really the best program for this. VisualBCD, while a bit trickier to use, is much better overall.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Windows, if it updates the bootloader, will make it so your computer boots into the Windows bootloader instead of GRUB. To fix this, you can try using [boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/), which should bring GRUB back to the default.

Answer (score 0):

When using UEFI you should not add a non-Windows OS like Linux to Windows boot menu.

It makes no sense as Windows boot manager cannot (chain)load "foreign" systems using Windows UEFI boot manager.

Every installed system(Linux, Windows etc.) on UEFI firmware writes its UEFI boot related data in NVRAM.

It is UEFI firmware boot manager which starts a selected Linux/Windows UEFI boot manager/loader.

To sum up - boot menu entries for Linux/Windows dual/multi boot installations on UEFI are stored in NVRAM !

**Note:**

Windows makes a copy of some common and some proprietary(Linux, Ubuntu) UEFI NVRAM variables to BCD and in system registry not belonging to Windows boot chain so **you can really chain load Linux from Windows BUT using UEFI firmware boot manager** - see [BootNext utility](http://www.boyans.net/bootnext/bootnext.html))